# R - advanced looping between variables

Tags: r, loops, probability

I am looking to do some advanced looping/probability regarding selling prices of a variety of products (thousands) to two different channels. Here is some sample raw data that is in an appropriate format for this logic I believe:

```
SKU <- c('sku1','sku1','sku2','sku2','sku2','sku3','sku3','sku3','sku3','sku4','sku4','sku5','sku5','sku5','sku5','sku5','sku5','sku6','sku6','sku6','sku6','sku6','sku6','sku7','sku7','sku7','sku7')
PRICE <- c(10,20,25,25,40,31,32,33,34,41,42,50,51,52,53,54,55,60,61,62,63,64,65,70,71,72,73)
QTY <- c(1,2,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,1)
AREA <- c('area 1','area 2','area 1','area 2','area 2','area 2','area 1','area 2','area 2','area 1','area 2','area 2','area 1','area 2','area 2','area 2','area 2','area 2','area 1','area 2','area 2','area 1','area 2','area 2','area 2','area 1','area 2')
df <- data.frame(SKU,PRICE,QTY,AREA)
```

What I want to know for each SKU is the # of times the price is greater in area 1 vs area 2, # of times greater in area 2 vs area 1, # of times equal, total combinations, and the %s of each of these 3 times.

Total combinations for each SKU would be =

(area 1(# of unique prices * quantity)) * (area 2 (# of unique prices * quantity))

Here is an example of the final output:

```
sku_name <- c('sku1','sku2','sku3','sku4','sku5','sku6','sku7')
area1greater <- c('0','0','1','0','1','7','3')
area2greater <- c('2','3','3','1','4','5','1')
areasequal <- c('0','1','0','0','0','0','0')
total_combos <- c('2','4','4','1','5','12','4')
df2 <- data.frame(sku_name,area1greater,area2greater,areasequal,total_combos)
```

and %s will be easy from here as it would just be the 3 areas divided by total combos

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're calculating here.  A good start might be to figure out the code for the calculation for a single SKU.

Comment: you have the formula, why didn't you try it?

Comment: Okay thanks will edit it shortly - with a better description

Comment: that formula is just for the total combinations - I think i need to create two arrays for each SKU (one for each area), and then loop on the first price of area 1 array to look at how many times it is greater than area 2 prices, then loop on the 2nd price of area 1 array to see how many times that is greater than the area 2 prices etc..

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on the case of a single SKU first, to get the underlying formula.

There's probably a more elegant way to solve this, but we can use `outer` to generate the outer product of the price lists for the two areas, `rle.inverse` to generate a flat version of the price list (so that if 60 appears with a quantity of 2, we would just show 60 twice), and then `sign` to get the differences to be `{-1,0,1}`, and `table` to get the counts for each.

In simplified form, we look at `sku6` --

```
> table(sign(outer(c(60, 62, 63, 65), c(61, 64, 64), '-')))

-1  1
 7  5
```

Which gives us the desired result.

```
comparesku <- function(df) {
   df.split <- split(df, df$AREA)
   area1 <- df.split[[1]]
   area2 <- df.split[[2]]
   flat.area1 <- inverse.rle(list(lengths=area1$QTY, values=area1$PRICE))
   flat.area2 <- inverse.rle(list(lengths=area2$QTY, values=area2$PRICE))
   table(sign(outer(flat.area1, flat.area2, '-')))
}
```